# How to expose the scoped region(manager) to the ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-core, prism

I cannot get the Scoped Region/RegionManager in the ViewModel. In a Prism project (.NET Core 3, Prism 7.2), I have a scoped region manager created in the module OnInitialized Method.

How do I expose this to a ViewModel in the module (for navigation)?

Comment: Why do you need a scoped region manager in the first place? Normally, you can just use the region manager that's there already.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply pass IRegionManager in the constructor of the viewmodel.
Prism dependancy injection system will take care of the rest.
You have the Register the regionManager on the Container first though.

```
private IRegionManager _regionManager;
public ViewModel(IRegionManager regionManager)
{
 _regionManager = regionManager;
}

public void Navigate()
{
 _regionManager.RequestNavigate(<regionName>, <viewName>);
}
```

Comment: That won't work, unless you don't need the real region manager, as registering the scoped one will override it.

Comment: So any suggested way to do this?

Comment: I will for sure need the "global" RegionManager (for other modules not mentioned above), so any suggested way to do this?
Can I define some kind of locally scoped (within one module) service which may be injected into the viewmodel and holds the scoped RegionManager?

Forgot to say that I a using Prism 7.2 for .net core and I am using the prism templates implying ViewModelLocators in views.

Strangely I find it hard to find samples other than the simplest which only touch the surface of Prism.

Comment: To be clear - this will work if you don't use a scoped region manager. See my comment above - why do you want a scoped region manager at all? You can have scoped regions without a scoped region manager. Also, if you can go view model first, do it. The view model locator is meant mainly for the topmost views.

Comment: Thanks a lot.
I do not have a preference for view-first and I will try to change to viewmodel first.
Please hint on how to have scoped regions without scoped regionmanagers
(I have used Prism for some time, but never scoped regions and region name collision possibilities before)